# rails activerecord expanding the dataset to include joineddata

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

We're trying to use json to pass marker data to google maps.

Up till now we were just pulling the dataset we needed (which dont include coordinates), and then extracting the coordinates the view using a belongs_to relationship. eg:

controller:

```
@clubs = Clubs.all
```

view:

```
@clubs.each do |club|
  lng = club.town.longitude
  lat = club.town.latitude
end
```

Now we want to pull the data through json. This means that the belongs_to is no-longer available in the view, so we need to append the long and lat data to the json @clubs dataset inside the controller so that we are able to do:

```
@clubs.each do |club|
  lng = club.longitude
  lat = club.latitude
end
```

How do we do this, or is there another way we can get round this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include 'town' association in club:

```
club.as_json(:include => :town)
```